# Adding text to a bitmap in memory in Android

Tags: android, graphics, canvas, bitmap

I'm trying to take a bitmap from resources, add a text message to it and return it to the caller of the method. It seemed like Canvas might be the method but the code below does not work.

```
public Bitmap annotateBmp(String storyId) {
    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(m_Context.getResources(),     R.drawable.candle_android_pin_512);

    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    Paint p = new Paint();

    p.setColor(R.color.red);
    c.drawText("Do you see this?", 30, 210, p);

    return b;   //Why does b not have the text?
}
```

Did I miss a step or is there a better method?

Comment: Do the canvas.drawText() in the draw() @override method. Tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and crashed on the first line.
since the bitmap is immutable, so i have to add a line to create a mutable bitmap.

```
b = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

then, your code just work fine. you do not specify the textSize, but this is not the reason. I think may be the origin coordinate of the text is out of the bitmap so you cannot see the text.

Comment: Thanks faylon! That did the trick. I had a mutable within the context I was working in but the default font was too small for me to see easily!