# Recording text/image overlay on Android

Tags: android, camera

How can I put text or transparent image into a video? I can display text overlayed camera output but how can I record it? Using opencv is an alternative but I don't really want to use opencv manager(or 25+ mb binary).

Is there a way to record overlayed video with Android SDK or 3rd party library. What are my options?

Update: I'm not looking for a "record to disc then load recorded video and process every frame" solution. I'm trying to find a way to process every camera frames before recording. Something like opencv.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620560/video-processing-in-android) to get video byes array of each frame from camera and then save them using some third party encoder. Now you can create `bitmap` from `byte array`, and using `bitmap` you can write a `overlay text` on it. Example code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184506/adding-text-to-a-bitmap-in-memory-in-android) and here is the link for the third party encoder  [AndroidFFmpeg](https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg)

Comment: "save them using some third party encoder", actually this is what i'm asking. My problem isn't getting video frames, i can already process it and display. I'm looking for a solution to record it properly or process camera frames before recording.

Comment: Check my updated answer. There is a library with example codes.