# How to record a video that each frame has watermark in Android?

Tags: android

**Is it possible to add a watermark when the frame is generated ?**

A watermark means to add text on picture or bitmap. [Adding text to a bitmap in memory in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184506/adding-text-to-a-bitmap-in-memory-in-android) has given an example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding watermark bitmap over video in android: 4.3's MediaMuxer or ffmpeg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358489/adding-watermark-bitmap-over-video-in-android-4-3s-mediamuxer-or-ffmpeg)