# Draw Text Over Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable

I'm trying to put text over map marker but it always appears under it.
First I convert drawable to bitmap and then draw text on it. drawable to bitmap conversion works fine, I only have a problem with text overlay.

[image]

I have already tried these:

1. [Adding text to a bitmap in memory in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184506/adding-text-to-a-bitmap-in-memory-in-android#7184755)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7328777/3423468
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/8831182/3423468

and many more with no luck.

This is my current method:

```
Bitmap drawableToBitmap(Drawable drawable)
    {
        var bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        var canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        if (shouldDrawText)
        {
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(40);
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER)); // Text Overlapping Pattern

            //canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
            canvas.drawText("Testing...", 10, 10, paint);
        }
        drawable.SetBounds(0, 0, canvas.Width, canvas.Height);
        drawable.Draw(canvas);
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered using the drawable as a `compound drawable` **inside** the TextView?

Comment: yes but as long as I need that for map marker I skipped it.

Comment: Any updates on how you solved this issue please?

Answer (score 4):

```
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER)); // Text Overlapping Pattern
```

Here you use SRC_OVER, which means the source will be over the DST will be under. The DST is the new pixels to be drawn.

You should use `DST_OVER` to draw the new pixels on top of the old pixels.

```
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER)); // Text Overlapping Pattern
```

See here an overview of how porterduff works
 [image]

Comment: Well elaborate .Move ahead

Comment: thanks for the answer but doesn't seem to be enough. I'm missing something

Comment: What's also important is to verify the order of drawing